# How many data points are required for one revolution?

Tags: signal-processing, fft

Hello I have a question about an FFT.
I have recorded the vibration of a gearbox with a sampling rate of 48kHz. The speed of the input is 50Hz, the speed of the output is 12.5 Hz. 
At a sampling rate of 48kHz I have 48000 data points per second and after the output rotates 12.5 times per second I have (48000/12.5) 3840 points per rotation.

Does it make a difference if I use only 3840 points for the FFT (i.e. 1 revolution) or if I use 48000 points and thus have 12.5 revolutions?

If someone has literature on this or can explain to me whether there are rules for this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Note that if you want to be able to see effects such as [oil whip/whirl](https://www.machinerylubrication.com/Read/754/oil-whirl-whip) then you’ll want several revolutions of the output of the gearbox.

Answer (score 0):

The more points you use, the higher the frequency resolution of the FFT result.  In vibration analysis, often the higher harmonics of the rotation frequency are important, which higher frequency resolution will better pinpoint and separate from any noise.

If you can use an integer multiple of one period of revolution as your FFT length, there will be less windowing artifacts (so called "leakage").  So maybe a length close to 12*3840?